# Cannot save Entitlement and Support Record Update Rule. Has anyone executed a workaround?

Tags: entitlements

I have an entitlement process covering a large number of cases and entitlements. I am unable to save an Entitlement and Support Record Update Rule to update existing records to a new version of the entitlement process. Naturally, if you can't save the update rule, you can't run the update rule, so this prevents updating existing assets to the new version.

To prevent this issue from delaying a deployment, I'm considering a workaround to manually update the small set of cases and entitlements affected by the new version of the entitlement process. Has anybody carried out such a workaround and if so, did you learn any lessons or encounter any gotchas?

Comment: If the case is already related to an Entitlement then updating Entitlement Process version will not automatically in effect. Only for new case creation, new entitlement process will be in effect via Entitlement.

Comment: This is true, and this is why Salesforce as the Entitlement and Support Record Update Rule feature. It's this feature which allows you to update existing cases and entitlements. But of course when the feature doesn't work, you can't use it, hence my question :>).